# Star domain are regular

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, diffeomorphism

Are all closed star-shaped domains in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with d-dimensional interior, regular closed sets?  I know all closed star-shaped domains have a star-shaped interior and all d-dimensional open star-shaped domains $\mathbb{R}^d$ are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^d$ itself.  Is that enough to conclude that they are regular closed sets or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a counterexample. Let $d = 2$, and consider the union of the closed disk of radius $1$ with the $x$-axis. Taking the closure of the interior leaves you with only the closed disk.